# “file doesn’t exist” or “file doesn’t exists”

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, subject-verb-agreement

> You’ve requested the example.txt file. That file doesn’t exist/exists.

Which one should I use? Why?

Comment: I would write "There's no such file."

Answer (score 44, accepted):

*That file doesn't exist.*

In any verb construction (auxiliaries + lexical verb) only the first is inflected for tense, person and number.

In your example *does* is the first verb in the construction *does exist*. Auxiliary *do* always takes an infinitive (plain) form as its complement: *exist*.

Comment: And for the plural, those files don't exist.

Answer (score 19):

A note from me:

(3rd sing.)

> - file exists
> - file doesn't exist

(3rd pl.)

> - files exist
> - files don't exist

Answer (score 5):

The right form is: The file doeSn't exist.

Gramatical explanation: always when you're forming a positive sentence about a 3rd person (singular only) in present simple tense, you have to add the letter s to the verb which describeS what he doeS.

Butwhen you're forming a negative sentence, as in your example, then this letter S goeS to the negative auxiliary verb instead to the verb itself. That's why in the sentence "The file doesn't exist" we don't add S to the verb exist, since this leeter already in the negative auxiliary verb (doeSn't rather than don't).